# How to assign File's Owner when using UITableView registerNib: to load a custom UITableViewCell from nib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So i've been looking at using `UITableView's` `registerNib:` and `[dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:]` for loading up a custom `UITableCellView` from a `NIB`. Here are the important bits from my controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

[super viewDidLoad];
self.tableView.bounces = NO;
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ProgramListViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

TVProgramListTableViewCell *cell = (TVProgramListTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CELLWIDTH, OPENCELLHEIGHT);
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.clipsToBounds = YES;

cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"herpa derp: %i", indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

So i'm registering the `NIB` when the view loads and then utilizing it for cell dequeuing. Up to this point everything is working like i expect it to. My custom `TVProgramListTableViewCell` is being properly loaded from the `NIB` and it's `IBOutlet` is being wired up.

The `NIB` contains a view with a button in it that i would like to have fire events to the controller. I can set the File's Owner type as my Table View Controller class but i do not know how to actually wire up the File's Owner.

Now if i was using `loadNibNamed:`, and loading the `NIB` myself, wiring up the File's Owner would be easy. Is there any way to achieve this while utilizing `registerNib`? Other than not being able to wire up the File's Owner this seems like the perfect way of using custom cells in a `UITableView`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no way to set the file's owner to your table view controller and connect up an action method to a button in a xib file -- I've tried that, and it crashes the app. The way this is normally done is to call addTarget:action:forControlEvents: on your button in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, and pass self as the target.

Comment: Yeah I went back to using loadNibNamed: when the cell is being dequeued. This allows me to set the owner to my controller as well as get the IBOutlets in my custom cell. So no need for calling addTarget as I can bind the button event to File's Owner in IB and it will be routed to my controller while still mapping my UIViews to the outlets in my custom UITableViewCell.

Comment: @VilleRinne, I think that registering the nib is more efficient (which is why Apple introduced it) than loading the nib for every cell that you create.

Comment: Yeah it may be more efficient but it is not very useful if you can't bind the controller to the File's Owner of the nib? Is efficiency really an issue anyways, since the nib is only loaded whenever a cell can't be dequeued?

Comment: @VilleRinne, why is it not very useful? It's just as easy to add a line for adding the target action for the button as it is to put in the load nib line.

Comment: @rdelmar in cellForRowAtIndexPath how do you avoid adding actions more than once to the same cell, given that dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier never returns nil when there's a nib registered?

Comment: @NateCook, I usually do this (if I'm adding views in code) by putting all the creation of subviews and adding actions in an if block, that checks for whether there is a view with a certain tag. Give one of the UI elements a unique tag and then have everything inside an if ([cell.contentView viewWithTag:101] == nil) so any cell that you've already configured won't get things added to it a second time. But usually I don't do it this way at all. I make the cell in the storyboard, and connect the button's action to the controller there.