# How to set File's Owner to a custom UITabelViewCell loaded from nib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder, uinib

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` loaded from a xib file and instantiated with a view controller as its owner:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    UINib *templateCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCell" bundle:nil];
    UITableViewCell *_templateCell = [[templateCellNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    [self.tableView registerNib:templateCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:_templateCell.reuseIdentifier];
}
```

Everything works fine, but `File's Owner` is null so I can't get access to my view controller from the inside of `TableViewCell` implementation:

```
@interface TableViewCell ()

// File's Owner placeholder outlet
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet TableViewController *fileOwner;

@end

- (void)setUpCell {
    ...
    NSLog(@"File's Owner: %@", self.fileOwner); // outputs "File's Owner: (null)"
}

@end
```

Why is the `File's Owner` property not set? And is there any way to wire up a view controller to the `TableViewCell` nib?

Comment: You shouldn't need to acces the view controller from a cell. What do you need it for? Maybe it can be achieved using delegation?

Comment: try this way `[self.tableView registerNib:templateCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"YourCellReusableId"];`

Comment: duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16160351/751932